# Can't store data to database

Tags: vb.net, ms-access-2013

There are no errors when my query is executed, but no data stored. What could be wrong?

My database is employee with id, first_name, middle_name, last_name fields.
id is auto number, the rest is short text

I'm using MS Access.

```
Imports System.Data.OleDb

Public Class AccountReg
    Dim dbProvider As String
    Dim dbSource As String
    Dim connString As String
    Dim myConnection As OleDbConnection = New OleDbConnection

    Private Sub Button1_Click(sender As System.Object, e As System.EventArgs)Handles Button1.Click
        dbProvider = "Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;"
        dbSource = "Data Source=|DataDirectory|\PIA-AMS.accdb"
        connString = dbProvider & dbSource
        myConnection.ConnectionString = connString
        myConnection.Open()
        Dim str As String
        str = "INSERT INTO employee (first_name, middle_name, last_name) VALUES (?,?,?)"
        Dim cmd As OleDbCommand = New OleDbCommand(str, myConnection)
        cmd.Parameters.Add(New OleDbParameter("first_name", CType(TextBox1.Text, String)))
        cmd.Parameters.Add(New OleDbParameter("middle_name", CType(TextBox2.Text, String)))
        cmd.Parameters.Add(New OleDbParameter("last_name", CType(TextBox3.Text, String)))

        Try
            cmd.ExecuteNonQuery()
            cmd.Dispose()
            myConnection.Close()
            TextBox1.Clear()
            TextBox2.Clear()
            TextBox3.Clear()
        Catch ex As Exception
            MsgBox(ex.Message)
        End Try
    End Sub
End Class
```

Comment: `|DataDirectory|`  = you are probably looking at the wrong database.  When you run your development, you are probably looking at a copy of the database.  No need to convert a TextBox.Text property to a string — it's already a string.

Comment: Suggest you see if `cmd.ExecuteNonQuery()' is returning 1.

Comment: Good job on using parameters!